# unsigned integer error while trying to convert pandas dataframe to R's dataframe using rpy2

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I have the below data :

```
grp_m1      grp_m2      grp_m3      grp_m4
$50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75
$50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75
$150-$175       $150-$175       $150-$175       $150-$175
$100-$125       $100-$125       $100-$125       $100-$125
$150-$175       $125-$150       $125-$150       $125-$150
```

These are then converted to dummies. The dtype of these dummies is unsigned int in the `pandas` dataframe, and when I try to convert into this into an R dataframe by using the below code:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
pandas2ri.py2ri(data)
```

I get the error below:

```
Error while trying to convert the column "grp_m4_$175-$200". Fall back to string conversion. The error is: Cannot convert numpy array of unsigned values -- R does not have unsigned integers.
  (name, str(e)))
C:\Users\hduser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.1\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py:61: UserWarning: Error while trying to convert the column "grp_m4_$200-$225". Fall back to string conversion. The error is: Cannot convert numpy array of unsigned values -- R does not have unsigned integers.
  (name, str(e)))
```

Can this be fixed or do I need to remove those columns all together, e.g. just skip the column if this error is coming?

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I don't speak python but I wouldn't be surprised if the solution was converting these values to signed integers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `astype()` from `pandas` in order to convert all of the elements in a `pandas` dataframe to the desired `dtype`. In this case we just want to convert your dummy variables into something that R understands. Assuming that your dataframe is still named "data", try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# change unsigned integers to integers
n_data = data.astype('int64') # you could also try float64, if you want

# Check data type
type(n_data.iat[0,0])

# Output
# <class 'numpy.int64'>

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

pandas2ri.py2ri(data)
```

Comment: in my case it was an object type that I changed to FLOAT. weird that rpy2 cannot catch such a fish

Answer (score 1):

Marcus's answer helped me a lot.

In my instance,I think the main cause of this problem is that the item of **`Pandas.DataFrame`** were converted to **`numpy.uint8`** after being converted to dummy variable by **`pd.get_dummies()`**.

So,I just converted it to `'int64'` by `astype()` before  applying `pandas2ri.py2ri(data)` and finally I fixed the bug.